# How to use TypeScript on a button click

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use typescript in my application. for the same I am doing an POC and in POC i want to call a function Defined in TypeScript class on button click.

Is it possible to call the function?
If yes then how?

So far I have seen examples where the functions are called on Page load only.
I need to call a function on certain event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to call a function on certain event.

If the function is global e.g. TypeScript:

```
function foo(){
   alert('foo');
}
```

Just use `onclick` e.g. html:

```
<button onclick="foo()">click me!</button>
```

Remember TypeScript *is* (almost) JavaScript.

However I recommend using a framework like angular with TypeScript. For maintainability. As an example take a look at [the browser quickstart](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/browser).

Comment: this is not working at all for my use case with typescript.

Answer (score -3):

**HTML WILL BE:**

```
<button (click)="myMethod($event)">Click Event</button>
```

**function in .ts file**

```
private myMethod(event:any):void
{
   alert(JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

Comment: need help on this(type script):
My code:

const new_H1: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement("button");
            new_H1.innerText="abc";
            <b>new_H1.onclick(alert("abc"):void);</b>
            this.target.appendChild(new_H1);

bold line is giving the error(syntax)?