# How to use EventTarget in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dom-events

Hey I am new to Typescript and I am having some trouble implementing Event Target.

What is the typescript equivalent for event.target.matches that is used in Javascript?

Example code:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'd need to cast ([type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)) `event.target` as something like a `HTMLElement` to provide access to `HTMLElement` methods such as `matches()`. Without the cast, `event.target`is typed as `EventTarget` which is why you are not seeing `matches()` or other `HTMLElement` methods being available.

```
if (!(<HTMLElement> event.target).matches('.dropbtn')) { }
```

Here is an [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.className%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function%20(event)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!(%3CHTMLElement%3Eevent.target).matches('.dropbtn'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('Does%20not%20match')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B) in action.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!(<HTMLElement> event.target).matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Per the suggestions from @WsCandy you could also use `as` as an alternative:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
      const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
      if (!target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
```

Comment: I'll just add to this. The `as` syntax is also available to do the same thing and a bit more readable. `const element = e.target as HTMLElement;`

Comment: Thanks very much I updated my question, and gave some code. How would I cast an assertion?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect how it would be done in your code

Comment: Just one question, how would I assign onClick to a function in type script, for example: <button onClick="myFunction()" className="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>

Comment: I'd recommend to create a new question to answer your question, but you have a couple of options. One option is utilizing [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in your TypeScript file against queried DOM elements such as `document.getElementById("someButtonId").addEventListener('click', (event) => { const target = event.target as HTMLElement });`. Otherwise you need to specify a global function such as [How to use TypeScript on a button click
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152463/how-to-use-typescript-on-a-button-click)

Comment: In case of using React `function({target}: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>)`

Comment: `as` type-casting should only be used as a last resort, as it can lead to errors. It is safer to check that `event.target` is actually an instanceof `HTMLElement`

Answer (score 3):

event.target in some cases can be `null`, `window` or `document`. It is not guaranteed to be an `HTMLElement`.

Instead of type-casting (forcing) it to an `HTMLElement`. It is safer to check that it is an HTMLElement.

```
if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) { ... }
```

Now event.target will be of type HTMLElement, and it is safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define an interface that extends `Event` and describes the type of `target` involved, and then use that interface in the function parameters. For example:

```
interface HTMLEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLElement;
}

window.onclick = function(event: HTMLEvent) {
...
}
```

If you are only concerned with typing `target` correctly, you can also define it inline like this:

```
window.onclick = function(event: { target: HTMLElement }) {
...
}
```